# NoSuchElementException found in Selenium webdriver while trying to use CssSelector

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to use use `cssSelector` instead of `xpath`. I opened CNN website and took the `xpath` of Politics at the top. Then tried to select it using `cssSelector`. I am unable to figure out whats wrong in the `cssSelector` that I have written. I am getting `NoSuchElementException`

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id='nav'] div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(3)"}

here is the code

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://cnn.com");
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='nav']/div[2]/div[2]/a[3]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id='nav'] div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(3)")).click();
```

Comment: can you please post the logs

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id='nav'] div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(3)"}

Comment: 1. do you actually have 4 children? nth-child numbering starts from 0, not one

Comment: 2. are the elements loaded statically or dynamically by JS?

Comment: Static. The xPAth doesn't change. I tried with with nth-child numbering 0.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[id='nav'] div:nth-child(1) div:nth-child(1) a:nth-child(2)")).click();


Still i get the error. All i am trying to do is click the Politics section taken from the same root element given in the xPath

Answer (score 0):

The second `div:nth-child(2)` in your selector should actually be `div:nth-child(3)`, the first `<a>` tag is also a child. You should also don't use `*` with `cssSelctor`

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id='nav'] div:nth-child(2) div:nth-child(3) a:nth-child(2)")).click();
```

You could also use class `nav-menu-links` as start point

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='nav-menu-links'] a:nth-child(2)")).click();
```

Or partial `data-analytics-header` attribute

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[data-analytics-header*='main-menu_politics']")).click();
```

Comment: Well, when i trace the HTML, doesnt CSSSelector follow the same rules as xPath.

Comment: Well, that element gives me World section and not Politics.

Comment: @Chetu19 Not necessarily.

Comment: @Chetu19 You need `a:nth-child(2)`, not `a:nth-child(3)`. Its in my answer.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using \*. You don't *need* it in this case, but even if it's there it's not hurting anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big proponent of CSS selectors over just about anything else but in this case I would probably use link text instead of a CSS selector. After that, I would use an XPath like `//div[@id='nav']//a[.='Politics']`. If I had to use a CSS selector, I would use `a[data-analytics-header='main-menu_politics']`.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, if possible avoid `:nth-child` and rather use classes, ids or other (more or less) unambiguous attributes to find an element.

For example the XPath you provided points me towards the Money section on cnn.com, instead of Politics.

You should either use `[data-analytics-header='main-menu_politics']` or `.nav-menu-links__link[href='/politics']`.

Also, you can use `#nav` instead of `*[id='nav']` and `.CLASSNAME` instead of `[class='CLASSNAME']`. There is a handy overview of css selectors at [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).